# JavaScript SetInterval () is not working after clicking

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Hi I have wrote this code and it suppose to move the object every 3000 ms after clicking on the object, but some how the time its not working, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, I am just learning javascript; thank you very much

```
function move1() {
    var im1 = document.images[0];
    im1.onclick = function() {
        im1.style.left = parseInt(im1.style.left) + 1 + "px";
    }
}

function move2() {
    var im2 = document.images[1];
    im2.onclick = function() {
        im2.style.left = parseInt(im2.style.left) + 10 + "px";
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(move1, 100);
    setInterval(move2, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Well, it's weird you'd add click handlers every 100 and 3000 ms.

Comment: why would you do this? nothing changes when you add the new click event.

Comment: I just started doing java, I dont know any better yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the other way round. Every 3000ms you make it possible to move the image by 1px when clicking on it.

```
function move(el, ms, px) {
/* moves the el every ms by px
returns the interval id to clear the movement */
    return setInterval(function() {
        el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + px + "px";
    }, ms);
}
window.onload = function() {
    var im0 = document.images[0];
    var im1 = document.images[1];
    im0.onclick = function() {
        move(im0, 100, 1);
    };
    im1.onclick = function() {
        move(im1, 3000, 10);
    };
}
```

Comment: hmmm, then how come this wroks, my Prof gave me this

Comment: function move(){
  var im = document.images[0];

  im.style.left = parseInt(im.style.left)+1+"px";
 }

 window.onload=function(){
  setInterval("move();", 1000);
 }

Comment: Because the function in the interval really moves the element each time. And the interval starts onload. BTW: You can let your prof know he's a very bad coder... (element caching, passinge a function)

Answer (score 0):

Your move function registers the image on click, but doesn't actually do any  moving until the user clicks. What you want is more like this:

```
function move1() {
    var im1 = document.images[0];
    im1.style.left = parseInt(im1.style.left) + 1 + "px";
}

function move2() {
    var im2 = document.images[1];
    im2.style.left = parseInt(im2.style.left) + 10 + "px";
}

window.onload = function() {
    var im2 = document.images[1];
    im2.onclick = function() {
        setInterval(move2, 3000);
    }

    im1.onclick = function() {
        setInterval(move1, 100);
    }
}
```